# Reload Drools rules without relaunch

Tags: java, drools, kie

I have a `Java` `Drools` app running `7.4.1.Final` version, with a `.drl` file with its rules. My application allows generating a new `.drl` file at runtime, or modify the current `.drl` file.

I want to run this new `drl` file without to relaunch again my app. I know that if I relaunch again, it loads the new version of the rules file, but I want to avoid to stop the execution of the app. My application is a `.jar` application that I run using `java -jar` command. In the code below `CTES.Rules` contain the file system with the `.drl` file.

Is it possible?

I attach the code that I use to load my rules file:

```
private void build() throws Exception {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    kfs.write(ResourceFactory.newFileResource(new File(CTES.RULES)));
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
    KieSessionConfiguration conf=  SessionConfiguration.newInstance();
    kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession(conf);
    if (kieBuilder.getResults().hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        List<Message> errors = kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Errors:");
        for (Message msg : errors) {
            sb.append("\n  " + msg);
        }
        throw new Exception(sb.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("KieServices built: ");
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have read about KieScanner and also about KieModule. But I don't have clear how to include  new released in my app or how use KieScanner.

What I have to change in this code to allow the load of a new version of the `.drl` file (in `CTES.RULES`) without to stop my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use KieScanner to load rule dynamically. KieScanner uses local maven repository to dynamically load KieModule.
 You will get the details [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e1920)

Comment: I'm reading about this and I don't understand how to use KieScanner or KieJar in my project. I have a drl file in my file system and I read it from my application. Also, my application is a .jar that I run with java -jar command :(

Comment: kmodule.xml is used by the KieContainer to load kiebase. Follow the steps below:
1. Separate your Drl file and fact from your Kieseesion program. Then do `mvn install` use the `artifactId`, `groupId` and `version` to create 
 Kiecontainer. Then create KieScanner from the KieContainer

Comment: How I can separate my DRL file from my KieSession?

Comment: if you do  `mvn install` of our project the project jar will get uploaded to the local `.m2 repository` based on the `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` write your code like :

           `KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            ReleaseId rs= ks.newReleaseId("artifactId","groupId","version");
            KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(rs);
            KieScanner kieScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
            kieScanner.start(10000); `
Kiescanner will scan the local maven repo every 10 sec

Comment: I'm going to test :)

Comment: If I run my app in a server machine, do I have to copy my .m2 folder in the server machine??

Comment: That is not required. You should have a copy of that project in `.m2 repository ` in your server machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165880/discussion-between-jjmartinez-and-prog-g).

Answer (score 1):

Posting for latest solution- We are using drools with Spring boot, Spring cloud config, we were able to reload the rules in runtime using /actuator/refresh endpoint with @refreshscope on the @kiecontainer bean.

We have yml like below:

```
rules:
    app1:
      program1:
          rulesetkbasename
          rulesetkbasepackage
          rulesetfilelocation
          rulesetfiles
          rulesetKsessionname
    app2:
      program2:
          rulesetkbasename
          rulesetkbasepackage
          rulesetfilelocation
          rulesetfiles
          rulesetKsessionname
```

Comment: if possible,Can you please share the example